# Microsoft SSRS Reporting Services Matrix Report Indentation

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, reportingservices-2005

I have a Matrix Report built in SSRS, I have it grouped on the ID for the rows and grouped on the FirstName & LastName for the columns to create the needed report, however the only thing that I need to get to work is the to indent the second and third rows to start at the first column instead of after the last column of the first row as showing, how can I get that to work please?

Thanks in advance!

[image: SSRS Matrix Report]

[image]

Comment: show us your report design and your groupings for the matrix

Comment: looks like you have more than 1 rowgroup, also you have duplicate IDs with different names, is this correct?

Comment: @Harry, I added the groupings for the matrix for you!

Comment: @AlanSchofield, I have 1 rowgroup on the ID and 1 column group on firstname and lastname to show the multiple records per ID on the same row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you have created a column group based on FirstName + LastName. This will create a new column for each instance of this (so 1 column for each record as they are all unique).

What you need to do is assign a column number for each name with each ID.

Here I have reproduced your sample data and then assigned a value to `ColN` for each unique name within each ID.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (ID INT, FirstName varchar(20), LastName varchar(20))

INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
(25, 'Abby', 'Mathews'),
(25, 'Jennifer', 'Edwards'),
(26, 'Peter', 'Williams'),
(27, 'Johns', 'Jacobs'),
(27, 'Mark', 'Scott')

SELECT 
    ID, FirstName, LastName
    , ColN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY FirstName, LastName)
 FROM @t
```

This gives us the following output.

[image]

You can now use `ColN` in you column group instead of the expression you now have.

This will give you the desired output.

Comment: That was brilliant!! It worked exactly as required. Thank you so much for your help!